# Cual es el atajo de teclado para abrir NeoTree en AstroNvim?

Tags: lua, nvim

estoy intendado buscar atajos de teclado de NeoTree al usarlo en AstroNvim pero en la documentación se muestran diferentes mappeos a los que hay en mi configuración y no logro saber como abrirlo sin necesidad de hacer el comando :NeoTree,
Al intentar <ctrl + o> se me abre el arbol pero es como si fuera una nuevo panel, por lo que es molesto, solo quiero abrirlo normalmente y seguir navegando tranquilamente.

Esta imagen muestra los mappeados que venian por defecto en el archivo del "pluggin"

[image: este es el archivo neo-tree.lua]

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

no se si ya lo has enontrado pero por defecto es la barra espaciadora más la teca e, o sea:Leader + e

Puedes encontrar tdos estos atajos en la web https://docs.astronvim.com/basic%20usage/mappings

si por error modificaste la configuración por defecto tal vez la propia documentación te sirva para regresar todo como estaba